# Sketch How to open same file in multiple windows/tabs?

Tags: sketchapp

Is it possible to open the same `.sketch` file in multiple tabs/windows?

I tried `File -> Open Recents -> Myfile` and also opening it multiple times from the Finder but it just keep opening the same windows

Answer (score 0):

You save the file as template，then open from the template.

- to save as template

  File > Save As Template
- open from template

  File > New From Template > select your template

> If you want to change the template , you have to save the same name as your template name .

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. This would create multiple instances of the same template. The question was asking how to create multiple windows into the same file

Answer (score 0):

If I have you right, the feature you're looking for is known as Custom Views in Adobe Illustrator, accessible in the menus by "View" > "New view".

I was looking for this feature in Sketch just now, but was unable to find it.

Not really comparable, but I temporarily solved this itch by creating a new Sketch document as a throwaway "New View", and then dragging over a desired Page from the Pages panel above the Layers list in the sidebar of the source document.